# Windows 10 auto connect to 5GHz WiFi throws error after disconnection/restart/hibernate

Tags: windows-10, networking, wireless-networking, router

In my Windows 10 laptop if I disconnect (by simply disconnecting or after restart or hibernate or shutdown) from the WiFi 5GHz network and try connecting to it again then I get an error as "Can't connect to this network". To solve this, every time I need to go to `Settings > Network & Internet > Wi-Fi > Manage known network > select SSID of 5GHz network and click on Forget`, after this, I need to connect to 5GHz network by keying-in password again. This doesn't happen with the 2.4Ghz network of the same router, also this issue is not seen with smartphones used in my home.

How to solve this problem permanently?

**Technical specs:**

> *Router:*
>  make: TP Link
>  model: Archer C20 AC750
>  network type: DSL
>  DHCP: Enabled

> *Laptop:*
>  make: Dell
>  model: Latitude E5470
>  OS: Windows 10 Enterprise Version Build 18363
>  wifi hardware: Intel(R) Dual Band
> Wireless-AC 8260

Comment: Try updating the driver, or try an external USB Wireless card. I have 5 GHz here on this machine and it is very stable (weeks and months). Intel cards on both machines attached.

Comment: The drivers are upto date and as it's office property I can't add any extra peripherals :(

Comment: Update the firmware on your router and try a different wireless card. 5 GHz is picky but it definitely works.

Comment: You need to ask the company about adding the card and updating the computer router firmware, but I think stability needs these updates.

Comment: Well, router is mine, it's my home network. Currently nwe are in work from home. I checked with router firmware, it's the latest one which released nin 2019. I need to check with company of they can provide permission for attaching external WiFi cards.